# WriteProcessMemory() returns 487? Value found using CheatEngine

Tags: c++, memory-address

As written up there (^), I've got a problem with C++ and WriteProcessMemory(). I opened the Windows- Calc.exe, stored a number with  and opened CheatEngine. I found the number (changed it e.t.c.) and put it in this program:
(Note: I'm german; "Rechner" is equal to "Calculator")

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    int Value = 500;
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(0, L"Rechner");

    if (!hWnd) {
        cerr << "Can't find window" << endl;
        return 0;
        }

    DWORD PID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &PID);
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID);

    if (!hProcess) {
        cerr << "Process handle error" << endl;
        return 0;
        }
    int iSuccess = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)0x899FC6F60C , &Value, (DWORD)sizeof(Value), NULL);
    int i = 0;
    while (iSuccess == 0){
        i = i+1;
        cerr << "Failed " << i  << "  Error:   " << GetLastError() << endl;
        iSuccess = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)0x899FC6F60C , &Value, (DWORD)sizeof(Value), NULL);  //Here all begins
        }
    clog << "Done" << endl;
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 0;
}
```

Window got found, Process got found (No errors there..) But then, the "//Here all begins" line returns 0, and sets GetLastError() to 487. Like all of the followings.
If you know, what I've done wrong, please describe it noob-friendly, I began C++ yesterday.

Comment: `487` is `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` (Attempt to access invalid address). `0x899FC6F60C` is probably not mapped in the calculator process. Where does that address come from?

Comment: Error 487 equates to `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS`. What is that magic address you're trying to write to (or what do you think it is)?

Comment: Hard-coding addresses is a pretty questionable approach.  For one, the Address Space Layout Randomization feature was designed to defeat it.  But the most common failure mode is that you are using a 64-bit address in a 32-bit program.  So you are actually trying to write 0x99FC6F60C.  Change the project's platform target to x64 and try again.

Comment: The target (calc.exe) shall be x64.. It's a windows Application.

Comment: No it's x86 - is that a problem?

Comment: 0x899FC6F60C is definitely a 64-bit address. That certainly means your calc.exe is 64-bit. If your application is 32-bit, you won't be able to use a 64-bit address, just because `WriteProcessMemory` take a 32-bit address. As Hans mentioned, your application must be 64-bit to do that.

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) for a description of what the GetLastError codes mean.

In this case `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS`, Attempt to access invalid address.

This is due to the fact, that you are writing to a 'random' memory address. You cannot just take a number and hope that there will be memory in the other process at this address.

Comment: Especially since each process has its own virtual address space.

Comment: I found the Address using CheatEngine, but CE gave me 899FC6F60C, so I just put a 0x in front. Might that work?

Comment: I have no idea what CheatEngine does. And since modern operating systems randomize their virtual address space for user processes, you cannot be sure if the address is right. And it will/could be different every start of the application.

Comment: @ProgrammingDonkey You need to subtract the application's base address to make the address relative, then write to `[base + relativeAddr]` on consecutive starts. Also read up on [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)